# Who was cast for the role of Bill Gates?

Tags: character, steve-jobs

Watching the new trailer of  [Steve Jobs (2015)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2080374/) , I was wondering who played Bill gates.

As IMDb plot says, the movie

> Follows the life and legacy of Steve Jobs.

I'm thinking there must be Bill Gates character is also put in the movie.
I already tried IMDb full cast list and google but no use, so, I thought I should ask the experts. Anyone knows who was cast for the role of Bill Gates? Is there a character as such? Is the character deliberately kept as secret? Any interviews or quotes from the director or writers?

Comment: Um.... why do you think there "must" be a Bill Gates Character?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because imdb shows the entire cast, and no one was billed as Bill Gates.  if it's not in imdb i'm fairly certain there's no bill gates in the movie

Comment: @DForck42 but in interstellar Matt Damon's character Michael Mann was kept as a secret and was not in IMDb's cast list initially.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The film *Steve Jobs* is more about his legacy than his life and will consist solely of the events surrounding three separate product launches Jobs was involved with: the Mac in 1984, NeXT in '88 and the iMac in '98. As such, there's really little reason for there to be a Bill Gates in the film at all.